# Linux Mint (17.1) : Mouse click/selection delay

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 (Cinnamon) and I'm experiencing an annoying lagging when pressing the left mouse button on my laptop's touchpad. The lagging does not appear when I connect an external (USB) mouse or use other external peripherals. It feels like a delay of half a second (so in the range of milliseconds).

It's not always noticible but a typical situation would be when I'm trying to select text in a document and the selection would always start in the middle of the word I'm trying to select (i.e. moving the mouse cursor from left to right). Or when I'm trying to move a window and I'm moving away the mouse cursor too fast from the window frame then the window wouldn't follow.

When I boot Win7 on my laptop and start the same Linux Mint version as a virtual machine I do not experience this lagging. Thus it seems that my hardware is not the cause.

I was also checking LM's mouse settings but it seems there's no option for mouse click delays or anything related to that.

Could some explain what's going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5):

After some "duckduckgo"ing, I found a [bug report](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3725) that seemed to discribe the same problems but the given workaround did not work for me (i.e. for others it did):

- disabling the option "*Emulate middle click by clicking both left and right button*" in the mouse settings (which was already disabled and re-enabling didn't do anything either)

[image]

I found another [bug report](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3786). However, this one got closed without any fix or workaround. (Why?!)

After some more "ducking" I finally found a [workaround](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=183552) that did work for me in the end.

- the "Drag and drop" threshold settings in the mouse settings have to be set (from default 8) to 1 pixel.

[image]

However, it turned out that my Virtual Machine LM is not up-to-date or for some hardware-based reasons my actual installation of LM has a slightly different looking mouse setup appearance:

[image]

So, finally, changing only "Cinnamon drag threshold" to 1 pixel did the trick for me.

Comment: @v.oddou: Glad it helped. Mind if I ask, which release version of LM are you running?

Comment: debian 9. (not LM.) but it's an issue that is cross distrib. I've experienced it recurrently and I usually use debian, ubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu, LMDE, LM sonya.

Comment: Thanks for this ... it helped. Surpised that this problem is still around ... using Linux Mint 20.2